# How to get music files from an Android device?

Tags: android, android-music-player

I noticed most music player tutorials tell you to look for .mp3 files in the /sdcard/ directory, but I find this a completly dumb ideea as most people will not have the music in the root directory of the sdcard but in a subdirectory.
So how to list the music from all directories (a recoursive function to scan the card would take a very long time)?

Comment: It's a dumb idea to look for media files anywhere.  Use the `MediaStore` class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a time taking process as just a contentprovider query can do ur work.
Try this Sample for this purpose.[Follow drive link to download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C9Pqrvc_CWaHM0OXBpRzIwdHN5NzljUmliTDBrTlZQSmZz/edit?usp=sharing)